# Is there any good way to debug "String or binary data would be truncated?"

Tags: sql-server-2008

The year is 2010.

SQL Server licenses are not cheap.

And yet, this error still does not indicate the ***row*** or the ***column*** or the ***value*** that produced the problem.  Hell, it can't even tell you whether it was "string" or "binary" data.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The year is 2020. Human beings have still made no attempts to improve the lives of other humans.

Comment: For me `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` worked well :)

Answer (score 21):

A quick-and-dirty way of fixing these is to select the rows into a new physical table like so:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.MyNewTable FROM <the rest of the offending query goes here>
```

...and then compare the schema of this table to the schema of the table into which the INSERT was previously going - and look for the larger column(s).

Comment: This is the best idea I've heard yet.

Comment: Risk of some false positives there. When SSMS auto-defines column widths it often leaves a little extra wriggle room. That means you might see some looking like a problem that aren't the problem.

[This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143429/identifying-values-which-would-be-truncated-in-an-insert-query) to roughly the same question revealed this gem I hadn't known about:

`SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='MyTableName'`

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old one.  Here's a small piece of code that I use that helps.

What this does, is returns a table of the max lengths in the table you're trying to select from.  You can then compare the field lengths to the max returned for each column and figure out which ones are causing the issue.  Then it's just a simple query to clean up the data or exclude it.

```
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE ##temp (colname nvarchar(50), maxVal int)

DECLARE oloop CURSOR FOR

SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SOURCETABLENAME' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'

OPEN oLoop 

   FETCH NEXT FROM oloop INTO @col;

   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
      SET @sql = '
   DECLARE @val INT;
   SELECT @val = MAX(LEN(' + @col + ')) FROM dbo.SOURCETABLENAME;
   INSERT INTO ##temp
           ( colname, maxVal )
   VALUES  ( N''' + @col + ''', -- colname - nvarchar(50)
             @val  -- maxVal - int
             )';
      EXEC(@sql);
      FETCH NEXT FROM oloop INTO @col;
   END

   CLOSE oloop;
   DEALLOCATE oloop

   SELECT * FROM ##temp
   DROP TABLE ##temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way here is to use binary search.

Comment half of the columns in your code and try again. If the error persists, comment out another half of that half and try again. You will narrow down your search to just two columns in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the length of each inserted value with an if condition,  and if the value needs more width than the current column width, truncate the value and throw a custom error.

That should work if you just need to identify which is the field causing the problem. I don't know if there's any better way to do this though.

Comment: Right, of course that's the method I end up using.  My question is that, why doesn't SQL Server just tell you where it is *when it finds the problem?*

Answer (score 1):

Recommend you vote for the enhancement request on Microsoft's site.  It's been active for 6 years now so who knows if Microsoft will ever do anything about it, but at least you can be a squeaky wheel:  [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name)

Answer (score 1):

For string truncation, I came up with the following solution to find the max lengths of all of the columns:

1) Select all of the data to a temporary table (supply column names where needed), e.g.

```
SELECT  col1
       ,col2
       ,col3_4 = col3 + '-' + col4
INTO   #temp;
```

2) Run the following SQL Statement in the same connection (adjust the temporary table name if needed):

```
DECLARE @table  VARCHAR(MAX) = '#temp';      -- change this to your temp table name

DECLARE @select VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
DECLARE @prefix VARCHAR(256) = 'MAX(LEN(';
DECLARE @suffix VARCHAR(256) = ')) AS max_';
DECLARE @nl     CHAR(2)      = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

SELECT  @select = @select + @prefix + name + @suffix + name + @nl + ','
FROM    tempdb.sys.columns 
WHERE   object_id = object_id('tempdb..' + @table);

SELECT  @select = 'SELECT ' + @select + '0' + @nl + 'FROM ' + @table

EXEC(@select);
```

It will return a result set with the column names prefixed with 'max_' and show the max length of each column.

Once you identify the faulty column you can run other select statements to find extra long rows and adjust your code/data as needed.

Comment: I found this helpful for even dealing with numeric types.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good way really.
I once spent a lot of time debugging a very informative "Division by zero" message.

Usually you comment out various pieces of output code to find the one causing problems.
Then you take this piece you found and make it return a value that indicates there's a problem instead of the actual value (in your case, should be replacing the string output with the `len(of the output)`). Then manually compare to the lenght of the column you're inserting it into.

Answer (score 0):

from the line number in the error message, you should be able to identify the insert query that is causing the error.  modify that into a select query to include `AND LEN(your_expression_or_column_here) > CONSTANT_COL_INT_LEN` for the string various columns in your query. look at the output and it will give your the bad rows.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about when you know the query.  And this is the kind of manual debugging that I'm trying to avoid.  There could be many columns in the table, and there could be more than one causing the problem.  Surely what you're describing the computer's job, right?

Comment: tell the computer how to handle the exception. prevent it in the WHERE, by throwing out the rows, truncate them in your INSERT by doing `RIGHT(....,max_col_len_int)` and never get this error, just truncate it.  if you want the progam to handle it, use an IF EXISTS query before the INSERT to find any that will truncate.  If you layout your tables with the proper data types this doesn't happen. if you are loading external data, you need to code to handle these exceptions, **SQL SERVER can't read your mind and do what YOU want, it does what the TSQL says.**

Comment: Yes, I have resorted to that method quite often (although I use LEFT of course). But that only works for "string" fields (which, granted, are usually the culprit).  What I'm trying to avoid is manually eliminating each field, looking up the width of the target, etc etc.  Seems that SQL Server could save us a lot of time by printing information that it presumably already has.

Comment: I'm not asking for magic, and I understand that I have to write the statement defensively.  But is it really necessary for the message to be so vague?

Comment: @KM of course no one thinks the server should just quietly handle it. It's just that loading external data is all some DB people work on so we could really do with better diagnostics than this. Why couldn't MS give the option to write a list of the specific exceptions to a system log table?

Comment: @Adamantish why not add functionality to the OUPTUT clause to output failed rows into a `Fail` table and allow all the working rows to be inserted.

Comment: I don't know a way of doing that. The whole point of Output is it only lists what it's actually done. There's another SO question that's answered with an equivalent to that. Set ANSI_WARNINGS OFF then everything will insert except the problem rows. You can then see which they were with a NOT EXISTS.

However, that doesn't tell you which column(s) the trouble is in. In my case a regular overnight load of a big reporting table with 110 fields is what failed.

Comment: I just mean no amount of defensive coding would have helped because when there's more chars than you expected it usually means an uncontrolled business change you need to know about. It's got to fail loudly, not silently Right() it away and propagate a problem.

Comment: @Adamantish, my suggestion to add functionality to the OUTPUT clause was something I wish Microsoft would do.  You get INSERTED AND DELETED, why not add FAILED or something like that and you can route them into another table for analysis. you can prevent the error by doing something like `LEFT(your_bad_data, 500)`.

Comment: Ah ok. There's a syntactic neatness to that kind of implementation but it would still mean sullying the meaning of `OUTPUT` being about things that actually changed and could be technically tricky to put in place seeing as instead of reporting something from translog this would be doing something completely different.
If it remained syntactically equivalent you'd also need to laboriously write out all the fields to be OUTPUT on every single insert you ever did.

I reckon something like the PasteErrors system table that gets created in MS Access would be the way but only if `ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`

Comment: @Adamantish, you only need to do this when debugging this problem and not on every single insert you ever did.

Comment: @KM I'm starting to think you feel this problem should be kept hard to debug on principle. As you said yourself, whilst you might be making self-contained software, it's a different story for people doing ETL and other external loads especially as most failures will be in in production not testing. Whereas there's utility in not outputting all fields updated there's no utility in excluding the error check from certain columns so no reason to explicitly list them all.

Comment: @KM Not having a go btw. Have been happily using your code snippet answer for searching within code for years.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there isn't a row to point to because SQL didn't write the data to the table. I typically just capture the trace, run it Query Analyzer (unless the problem is already obvious from the trace, which it may be in this case), and quickly debug from there with the ages old "modify my UPDATE to a SELECT" method. Doesn't it really just break down to one of two things:

a) Your column definition is wrong, and the width needs to be changed
b) Your column definition is right, and the app needs to be more defensive

?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that worked for me was to put the rows first into a temporary table using select .... into #temptable
Then I took the  max length of each column in that temp table. eg. select max(len(jobid)) as Jobid, ....
and then compared that to the source table field definition.

Answer (score 0):

For bulk inserts using temp tables and varchars:

- use `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` to insert truncated values.
- Using SSMS generate a standard SELECT command from the destination table
- Replace all `[` with `LEN([` and all `]` with `])`, to see lenghts of all varchar fields.
- Use ChatGPT to name the fields for you and UNPIVOT the select for you. Just post the SELECT and ask him to do UNPIVOT. You get something

like this - you need to add GROUP BY by column name only and MAX() of Value:

```
SELECT ColumnName, MAX(Value)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        -- LEN([Zadavatel]) AS [Zadavatel],
        LEN([JmenoZadavatele]) AS [JmenoZadavatele],
        LEN([Prijemce]) AS [Prijemce],
        LEN([JmenoPrijemce]) AS [JmenoPrijemce],
        LEN([JmenoPrijemce]) AS [JmenoPrijemce2],
        LEN([ZalozenoDne]) AS [ZalozenoDne]
    FROM [_ZCSD54]
) AS Source
UNPIVOT
(
    Value FOR ColumnName IN
    (
        -- [Zadavatel],
        [JmenoZadavatele],
        [Prijemce],
        [JmenoPrijemce],
        [JmenoPrijemce2],
        [ZalozenoDne]
    )
) AS UnpivotData
GROUP BY ColumnName
```

Now check which columns are at MAX length - they have the truncated data problem.